# Crittercism crash report not delivered

Tags: c#, exception, crash, crittercism

i have made an account on [crittercism](http://www.crittercism.com/). I have developed Windows Phone 8 app and also installed the nuget package. then i have add the following code line in my `App()` function.

> Crittercism.Init("************************");

The complete code of my App function is something like that

```
 public App() {

        UnhandledException += Application_UnhandledException;

        // Standard XAML initialization
        InitializeComponent();

        // Phone-specific initialization
        InitializePhoneApplication();

        // Language display initialization
        InitializeLanguage();

        Crittercism.Init("****************");

        // Show graphics profiling information while debugging.
        if (Debugger.IsAttached) {
            // Display the current frame rate counters.
            Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;


            PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
        }

    }
```

i am crashing my app now in the debug mode for testing and i am not getting any crash report for that on my dashboard.

Any ideas that why i am not getting it will be helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the Crittercism nuget library are you using?  Could you try upgrading to v2.0.0?

http://www.nuget.org/packages/Crittercism/2.0.0

Take care and happy coding,
Rob
Co-Founder, Crittercism